# Java rotating and drawing with Graphics2d

Tags: java, rotation, graphics2d

```
    AffineTransform at;
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

    g2.setColor(Color.black);

    at = new AffineTransform();
    at.setToTranslation(x, y);
    at.setToRotation(theta);
    g2.setTransform(at);
    g2.drawPolygon(points);
```

My code draws a triangle at x and y... and when i press a and d the triangle rotates.. but when i press w and s, the triangle does not change its x and y.

The variables are correct.. it's the translation routine.. I'm not sure where i got wrong..

If i do this:

```
    AffineTransform at;
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

    g2.setColor(Color.black);

    at = new AffineTransform();
    at.setToTranslation(x, y);
    g2.setTransform(at);
    g2.drawPolygon(points);

    at.setToRotation(theta);
    g2.setTransform(at);
    g2.drawPolygon(points);
```

One rotates and one moves.. so why cant i apply both translations before drawing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    AffineTransform at;
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

    g2.setColor(Color.black);

    at = new AffineTransform();

    at.translate(x, y);     
    at.rotate(theta);
    g2.setTransform(at);
    g2.drawPolygon(points);
```

I was using the wrong things.. rotate and translate are the functions i needed.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle docs :

> To add a coordinate transform, use the transform, rotate, scale, or
>   shear methods. The setTransform method is intended only for restoring
>   the original Graphics2D transform after rendering.

There can be only one transform, in which you can concatinate new transformations for example for the rotate method:

> Concatenates the current Graphics2D Transform with a translated
>   rotation transform. Subsequent rendering is transformed by a transform
>   which is constructed by translating to the specified location,
>   rotating by the specified radians, and translating back by the same
>   amount as the original translation.

There is also a warning:

> WARNING: This method should never be used to apply a new coordinate
>   transform on top of an existing transform because the Graphics2D might
>   already have a transform that is needed for other purposes, such as
>   rendering Swing components or applying a scaling transformation to
>   adjust for the resolution of a printer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to concatenate both transformations into a single AffineTransformation.

i.e.

```
AffineTransform at, toConcatenate;
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

g2.setColor(Color.black);

at = new AffineTransform();
toConcatenate = new AffineTransform();

at.setToTranslation(x,y);
toConcatenate.setToRotation(theta);
at.concatenate(toConcatenate);
g2.setTransform(at)
g2.drawPolygon(points);
```

I based much of this on a tutorial found on Oracles site at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html

I think the reason your code doesn't work is that 'The setTransform method overwrites the Graphics2D object's current transform' You're overwriting the first transform with the second rather than concatenating the two.

Hope this helps